# Jquery slider inside popup dosen't work

Tags: jquery, popup, swiper.js

I am trying to program a slider inside a popup box.

I am using Jquery.
The popup works and it pops as i want to.

For the slider I use the Swiper jquery library.

If i test the code inside the popup div by it self the slider works great, but there must be some collision there.

This is the link to what i just described.

http://seveloff.com/test/popup.html

This is the pop-up code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).load(function() {
        $("div#slidex").append('<div class="pup disable"><div class="swiper-container"><div class="swiper-wrapper"><div class="swiper-slide"><img src="images/1.jpg" alt="pro group 1"></div><div class="swiper-slide"><img src="images/2.jpg" alt="pro group 2"></div><div class="swiper-slide"><img src="images/3.jpg" alt="pro group 3"></div><div class="swiper-slide"><img src="images/4.jpg" alt="pro group 4"></div></div> <div class="swiper-pagination"></div></div><img id="x" src="http://cmsresources.windowsphone.com/windowsphone/en-us/How-to/wp7/inline/basic-icon-x.png"> </div>');

        setTimeout(function() {
            $("div.pup").fadeIn(200).addClass("active");
        }, 3000);

        $('#x').on('click', function() {
            $("div.pup").fadeOut(300).addClass("disable");
        });
    });
});
```

I don't get any errors at the console.

I must be missing something...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to initialize the swiper when the target elements are not loaded yet. Also, as you are showing `div.pup` inside a timeout, you should initialize the swiper there.

Other thing you can improve is that you don't need to wait for load the DOM and the contents separately. In this case, waiting just for the DOM is enough.

You code should look like this ([jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kmsdev/uv14mzog/)):

```
$(function(){
    $("div#slidex").append('<div class="pup disable"><div class="swiper-container"><div class="swiper-wrapper"><div class="swiper-slide"><img src="http://seveloff.com/test/images/1.jpg" alt="pro group 1"></div><div class="swiper-slide"><img src="http://seveloff.com/test/images/2.jpg" alt="pro group 2"></div><div class="swiper-slide"><img src="http://seveloff.com/test/images/3.jpg" alt="pro group 3"></div><div class="swiper-slide"><img src="http://seveloff.com/test/images/4.jpg" alt="pro group 4"></div></div> <div class="swiper-pagination"></div></div><img id="x" src="http://cmsresources.windowsphone.com/windowsphone/en-us/How-to/wp7/inline/basic-icon-x.png"> </div>');

    setTimeout(function() {
        $("div.pup").fadeIn(200).addClass("active");
        new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
            pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
            nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
            prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
            slidesPerView: 1,
            paginationClickable: true,
            spaceBetween: 30,
            loop: true,
            autoplay: 2500,
            autoplayDisableOnInteraction: false,
            effect: 'fade'
        });
    }, 3000);

    $('#x').on('click', function() {
        $("div.pup").fadeOut(300).addClass("disable");
    });
});
```